# zsh <tab> <tab> autocompletion only if there is unique match

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I recently switched from bash to zsh and I am trying to figure out how to change the double tab autocomplete behavior. I'd like it to autocomplete only if there is a unique match.

Answer (score 0):

This can be controlled by shell options. You can try it in interactive shell first, then add your preferred options to `~/.zshrc`.

To make zsh auto complete behave more like bash, you can start with this:

```
setopt NO_AUTOLIST BASH_AUTOLIST NO_MENUCOMPLETE
```

Also check official zsh documentation, section 6 and especially subsection 6.2. Currently it can be found here: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide06.html#l147